# Exposing ID of currently executing promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing async code using native promises in Node 6.9.  I'm noticing a race condition where a new promise is firing, before the old promise has completed.

I'm printing out debugging, which is hard to read because one promise's output is interleaved with the other.  It would be helpful to have an "id" of some kind  that identifies which function is currently executing.

For example:

```
function doWork() {
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("queue ID", someId())
    // long-running processing happens
  })
}

doWork()
-> queue ID 1
doWork()
-> queue ID 2
```

Note: *I'm not looking for process.id*.  As I understand it, node runs in a single process, and async I/O happens within that, so printing out process.id is useless.

Comment: You could just make your own, a simple counter should do, where you start with `i=0` and just increment for each promise. What you're probably looking for is some way to queue promises within your function, but on the other hand just calling `new Promise` multiple times shouldn't cause a race condition at all ?

Comment: A race condition between two promises that causes you a problem means that you don't have them properly chained together such that one does not execute until the other finishes. What you are asking for is not built into the promise infrastructure. Since you likely know something about the promises that are involved in the problem, we'd stand a much better chance of helping you with the real problem if you showed the code for what you're trying to do and describe the problem you have. Instead, you've asked only about one particular debugging technique. We'd rather help with the real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as promise id, what you can do is use a named function and pre-pend that to you console logs or you can use closures to keep a reference to an arbitrary integer or string representing an id.

```
function doWork(someId) {
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("queue ID", someId);
    // long-running processing happens
  })
}

doWork(10)
-> queue ID 10
doWork(20)
-> queue ID 20
```